# scan bluetooth device once appearing the uicontroller

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am new in programming, I may be not able to use the proper terms to describe.

i am writing an app that i want the app once it appears on the screen. it automatically scans the device for 5 secs and put on the table view to show the details.

I also wrote an action method to respond the reload of UIBarButtonItem.
the action method works fine. It puts devices' information on the cell.

so, I put this action method into viewDidLoad block in order to scan the bluetooth devices once the view loaded.
 but it doesn't work. But I know when the controller pops up, the action method is running. but It doesn't show any information on the cell. I need to press reload to scan and list on the cell.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    btCentralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    btCentralManager.delegate = self

    actionScan(navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!)
}
```

the reload button:

```
@IBAction func actionScan(sender: UIBarButtonItem) { // works fine.
    sender.enabled = false
    navigationItem.title = "Scanning..."
    btConnectable.removeAll()
    btPeripherals.removeAll()
    btRSSIs.removeAll()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: #selector(ScanTableViewController.stopScan), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    btCentralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
}
```

How can I scan and list on the table once the controller pops up?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add CBCentralManagerDelegate method:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn {
            startScan()
        }
}
```

and add methods like this:

```
func startScan() {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.centralManager?.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: "stopScan", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func stopScan() {
        self.centralManager?.stopScan()
    }
```

If you want to run any method every time view controller appears on screen - call these methods from viewWillAppear, or from viewDidAppear.
viewDidLoad are called only once, when you load your view controller.

Comment: i have had this centralManagerDidUpdateState method. i followed you and put the scan action method into this block. and it works. thank you so much.